# Can IPython cell magics get access to a unique cell identifier?

Tags: ipython

I'm trying to implement magics to support a programming language where entire modules must be compiled at once. My goal is that all cells in a notebook with a particular cell magic will be coalesced into a single module `M`.

To make this work, when a cell `C` changes I need to remove the old contents of `C` from `M` and replace them with the new contents of `C`. However when the cell magic is called for `C`, there is no way to tell that it is `C` and not any other old or new cell. What I need is an identifier that is constant between calls to the cell magic.

Is this kind of cell identifier available anywhere in the IPython API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: the kernel (where execution happens) knows nothing about the notebook interface. From the kernels point of view, it receives some code to execute, and sends back some results. So running the same cell twice is exactly the same as running two cells with the same content.

I don't know what language you're working on, but other magics that require compilation treat one cell as one module. For instance, have a look at [the %%cython magic](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/extensions/cythonmagic.py).

Comment: I saw that; this might be the approach I'll have to take. Thanks!